# A question concerning grammatical structure

Tags: sentence-structure, adverb, adverbial

As I was working on a German workbook, I saw a sentence:

> Hoffentlich bringt der Kellner das Essen.

I wonder if I could change it to:

> Hoffentlich bringt der Kellner bald das Essen.

Comment: Without any context, the implication of the first sentence isn't set. If it is already a temporal context then adding `bald` might be possible without changing the implied meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is normal use case and the better one.  "Hoffentlich bringt der Kellner das Essen bald." is possible too.   The first sentence is used when you want to be served by a steward and not by back staff.

Comment: The first sentence is not incomplete. It just means something different.

Comment: @tofro yes you are right. I thought about just this moment.

Comment: Your interpretation is still not entirely correct. The speaker simply hopes he is going to be served by the waiter at all.

Comment: @tofro I would have come up with your interpretation too, but help-info's also makes perfect sense. Since the context is not given, I'm unable to say that only one is correct.

Comment: @help-info.de - Would it be ungrammatical to place "bald" right after the verb?

Answer (score 0):

The firs sentence:

> Hoffentlich bringt der Kellner das Essen.

Depending on how you express the sentence:

> Hoffentlich **bringt** der Kellner das Essen.

This way one expresses the hope, that there will be any food at all.

> Hoffentlich bringt **der Kellner** das Essen.

This way one expresses the wish to be served by the server and not eks. the cook.

> Hoffentlich bringt der Kellner bald das Essen.

By adding "bald", the meaning shifts towards a temporal expression.